# Actionscript: BlitMask stopping mouse event listeners from working, how to fix?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, gsap

I have a button class which contains event listeners to trigger an animation of the button on click.

I used many instances of this class to form a list which the user can scroll through. I have implemented BlitMask, this works, however the mouse event listeners in the button class no longer work. This code

```
_blit = new BlitMask(_mc, _obounds.x, _bounds.y, _bounds.width, _bounds.height, false);
```

Is what stops the button class.

How can I get the behaviour pre blitmark?

My code which creates the bottom is

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField(text);
tf.x = 70;
tf.y = 20;
_btn.addChild(tf);
_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);
```

click is never called.

Comment: Not sure how the BlitMask works under the hood.   Is this the Greensock class?  Most likely you just need to make sure the button is on top of the `_blit` (or disable mouse input on the _blit until the button is clicked via `_blit.mouseEnabled = false` then in your click handler set it to `true`)

Comment: Yes it is greensock. I do not want to add the listener to the blit because I need to manipulate the button inside the button class on click. Of course the event listener attached to the blit itself works.

Comment: Quote: *A BlitMask is basically a rectangular Sprite that acts as a high-performance mask for a DisplayObject by caching a bitmap version of it and blitting only the pixels that should be visible at any given time, although its bitmapMode can be turned off to restore interactivity in the DisplayObject whenever you want.*

Answer (score 1):

The blitmask causes the movieclip to be nothing more than an image of clip.

bitmapMode must be set to false to correct this.

```
_blitMask.bitmapMode = false;
```

EDIT: To expand on a further issue that implementing this solution causes, turning bitmapMode on only when needed causes the bitmap to not reflect changes in the classes that changed while bitmapMode was off. So you must set

```
_blitMask.update(null, true);
```

To force a full update when you use

```
_blitMask.bitmapMode = true;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the whole point of using `BlitMask` is to improve performance. So you might heed the advice in the [documentation](https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/BlitMask.html#bitmapMode) that says to enable `bitMapMode` during animations, and then to disable it (for interactivity). Otherwise, if you disable `bitmapMode` all the time, is there really any need to use it at all?